# How can I specify how many ec2 instances I want to use to distribute a load

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to make an app that estimates a value.

What I already have:

the app has a front end which is a form html page.

it uses POST to pass arguments/parameters onto a flask app that has the function that estimates a value and then it returns the estimated value back to the front end on a results html page.

This flask app is on an ec2 instance and its deployed using nginx and gunicorn and I can access it through the public DNS

What i Want:

I want the app to run on multiple instances by passing an argument from the front end to the flask.py file called "Number of Instances"

then collect all the values from the instances back to the front end.

I am sorry Im very new to coding

Comment: Why not create autoscaling group to automatically add the instances if needed?

Comment: how do I do that ?

Comment: Read through this documentation--there's a lot an auto-scale group, but this will give you all the steps for how to create one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html